# How to add a Timestamp in a saved backup file

Tags: c#, winforms, performance

I have been trying how to add a timestamp for my code right here I can't seem to get it right, what should I type?

```
File.Copy(CurrentDatabasePath, PathtobackUp + @"\BackUp.accdb", true);
```

Comment: Hi, and welcome to StackOverflow. Please provide more details. Where is the timestamp supposed to go? In the database file? In the file name?

Comment: `File.Copy(CurrentDatabasePath, $"{PathtobackUp}\\{DateTime.Now:dd'.'MM'.'yyyy}BackUp.accdb", true);` (if "TimeStamp" means day, month year in `dd.MM.yyyy` format)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the DateTime class like so:

```
File.Copy(CurrentDatabasePath, PathtobackUp + $"\BackUp_{DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString()}.accdb", true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try `Path.Combine` (when combining directory and file name) and *string interpolation* `$"{...}"`:

```
File.Copy(CurrentDatabasePath, 
          Path.Combine(PathtobackUp, 
                    $"{DateTime.Now:yyyy'-'MM'-'dd' 'HH'.'mm'.'sss}_BackUp.accdb"), 
          true);
```

Here I put timestamp in `yyyy-MM-dd HH.mm.ss` format e.g. `2019-03-07 14.36.55_BackUp.accdb`

Comment: Thanks a lot brother!